# Getting Error: First argument to verifyIdToken() must be a Firebase ID token string

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm making an `XMLHttpRequest` via `POST` method and then trying to get the `tokenid` to verify it in my `node.js` file. However, I keep on getting an error when I try to verify the token. I get an error saying:

> Error: First argument to verifyIdToken() must be a Firebase ID token string

---

This is how I'm making the `POST` request:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.setRequestHeader(
  "Content-Type",
  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
);
xhr.onload = function() {
   console.log("Signed in as: " + xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send("idtoken=" + user.getIdToken());
```

This is my code for the `node.js` file:

```js
app.post("/tokensignin", (req, res) => {
    admin
        .auth()
        .verifyIdToken(req.body.idtoken)
        .then(function(decodedToken) {
            let uid = decodedToken.uid;
            console.log("uid is " + uid);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
});
```

I have tried using `req.body`, and `req.body.token`, but the error persists. When I try to print the `idtoken`, I get `[Object object]`

Answer (score 1):

You are sendinging data using the field name called "idtoken":

```
xhr.send("idtoken=" + user.getIdToken());
```

But you are accessing it on your backend using a different name "token":

```
.verifyIdToken(req.body.token)
```

I suggest doing more logging in general in order to better understand what you're working with on both sides and debug what's going on.

Comment: That was the first thing that I tried. Since it was giving me an error as well, I tried doing req.body.token instead

Comment: Well, as I said, log everything if you have any doubt at all what's being sent or received.  We can't really debug like that for you.

Answer (score 0):

What do you get when logging the `request.body` object? You have `nodejs body parser` installed, right? Are you using your own NodeJS server (I am almost certain you do)? But my question is why not use the Firebase environment?